# Re-compile VIM with options

Tags: installation, vim, compile

I have VIM installed but I need to compile it with specific options:

```
In addition to the most commonly used features, the plugin
       requires: +python or +python3, +clientserver and +conceal.
```

What are steps to uninstall, and recompile with those options without breaking anything?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you compile vim you can pass the option/flag `--with-features`, e.g.:

```
--with-features=huge
```

This will determine which features are included in the install. A list of all features can be found here (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html) with a letter indicating which version the feature is included in:

```
Here is an overview of the features.
            The first column shows the smallest version in which
            they are included:
               T    tiny
               S    small
               N    normal
               B    big
               H    huge
               m    manually enabled or depends on other features
             (none) system dependent
            Thus if a feature is marked with "N", it is included
            in the normal, big and huge versions of Vim.
```

For example if you wanted arabic language feature you would have to have `--with-features=big`

```
                            *+feature-list*

   *+ARP*       Amiga only: ARP support included

B  *+arabic*        |Arabic| language support

N  *+autocmd*       |:autocmd|, automatic commands

... etc
```

Comment: This says "When you compile vim you can pass the option:...". It then goes on to show the huge option to get all/most features or something like that. What exactly do I pass that option to? Can I see an example?

Comment: The standard way of installing sourcepackages in linux applies here. Download the source code, run `./configure`, run `sudo make install`. It is during the `./configure` step that you can add options such as `--with-features``. See step 3 in https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

Answer (score 17):

First, you need to get the source code, easiest through Vim's *Mercurial* repository; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details.

Then, you need a build environment and the *dev* libraries, especially for the desired Python. This greatly depends on the platform. On Ubuntu / Debian, it's a simple

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome
```

An Internet search will tell you more.

To compile with the features, you pass those to

```
$ ./configure --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp
```

Watch its detection output closely.

Finally, you can compile and install:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This will (on Linux) install Vim to `/usr/local/bin/vim`, so it doesn't interfere with the default `/usr/bin/vim`, and you don't need to uninstall anything; just make sure that the former comes first in your `PATH`.

Comment: This will install +clientserver and +conceal options as well? It's a bit frustrating not knowing which --enable flags install the options I want.

Comment: Something else you might do is save the build configuration you have now with this command, `vim --version > vim-version.orig` and compare that with the output of `vim --version` after you've re-compiled vim. That will let you know if there are any features you used to have that did not get included in the re-compiled version.

Comment: @garyjohn thats a good tip! The problem for me was not knowing which configure flags would install the appropriate features

Comment: @IngoKarkat This did not compile with +clientserve =(

Comment: Nevermind, just forgot to start a new terminal session :)

Comment: By default, "most" features are enabled (if the dev libraries are there). To be sure, you can pass `--with-features=huge` to have everything in there.

Comment: The `vim-gnome` and `vim-gtk` packages both intall Vim with everything you need.

Comment: I'm confused. This says "To compile with the features..." To compile with what features? What exactly is happening at `./configure --enable-pythoninterp --enablepython3interp`?

Comment: @INTPnerd: Those are for the Python 2 and 3 interpreters. The `--enable-...` tell configure to check for the existence of the corresponding dev libraries and headers, and if everything's there, add the proper `#define`s that compile Vim with Python support.

Answer (score 3):

## Configure, Compile and Install Vim

Install required libraries

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
```

Download the latest VIM version from github, e.g.

```
mkdir -p ./git/vim; cd ./git/vim
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim
```

The **most practical  way to make the configuration** is to set configuration options directly in the **Makefile**.  First make a copy of the Makefile

```
cp ./src/Makefile ./src/Makefile.backup
```

If you are familiar with git the last step isn't necessary since you can easily restore the origin state of all files with `git clean -dfX` or simple restore the Makefile with `git restore Makefile`.

If you prefer to compile a *official* release you have to checkout as so called **tag**. To list available tags type `git tag --list`. To compile such a release you have to checkout a tag like `git checkout v9.0.1440`. From my experience there is noting wrong by directly compile the so called **master branch** (up to date source code).

Afterwards open the `./src/Makefile` and then **uncomment** (delete the **#**) lines you like to be compiled and installed.

```
vi ./src/Makefile
```

To adapt **features** you have to edit the `src/feature.h` file

```
vi ./src/feature.h
```

It is recommended for unix to make the basic choice by adding it to the `configure` command.

> **Basic choices are:**
>
> - **tiny**     - almost no features enabled, not even multiple windows
> - **small**      - few features enabled, as basic as possible
> - **normal**      - a default selection of features enabled
> - **big**           - many features enabled, as rich as possible
> - **huge**                - all possible features enabled

Then configure vim to apply your settings

```
./configure --with-features=huge
```

Afterwards simply compile

```
make -j `nproc` # compile with max. number of processors
```

and install it with

```
sudo make install
```